# The most interesting list

Tags: description

I want to describe the look of a room. In particular I would like for the reader to be overwhelmed by the many objects stacked on the shelves. This list of objects serves no purpose in the rest of the story other than giving the reader a >wow< moment when reading this particular passage.

I tried just going with the plain list, as if scanning the shelves with the eyes, but it ended up being as exciting as a catalogue from IKEA. Alternatively, I listed the items by grouping them, e.g. the statues, the books, the bottles, but that also had the feeling of some mail order catalogue. Giving the spotlight to some curious items, like a specific bottle, or a rare book, sounded equally bad and definitively did not produce any >wow<.

The question is: how to give the reader a sense of >wow< when making a list of all the objects in a scene?

Comment: Maybe you can use alliteration, rhyme and meter to give the list a compelling flow. A bit like the Sound of Music's ["My Favorite Things"](https://www.songlyrics.com/the-sound-of-music/my-favorite-things-lyrics/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Impressionism

> (Impressionist painters) portrayed **overall visual effects instead of
> details**, and used short "broken" brush strokes of mixed and pure
> unmixed colour—not blended smoothly or shaded, as was customary—to
> achieve an effect of intense colour vibration.
> [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressionism)

In other words, do not list physical objects, allow those things to be inferred. Instead describe the "wow".

*a frenzy of porcelain elbows and figurine skirts*…
*stern paper faces leaning in picture frames like neglected headstones*…
*a gaggle of goosenecked bottles, mouths open and hissing at the sky*…

I don't know your tone or the specific impression this bric-a-brac is meant to convey but try overwhelming the senses, especially shapes and colors. Describe things 'wrong' as if one object blurs into the next.

Make associations between 'factions' of objects that imply groups of people, neighborhoods, nationstates. Play with increasing the macrocosm as the narrator struggles to take it all in.

Give hints to the era, or their aspirations – sports or hotrod memorabilia suggests the boyhood desires of the collector. An enormous set of dish and glassware says something about fallen prosperity, or social graces that have passed. A hoarder will save useless things like wrapping and boxes, leaving valuable objects buried among trash.

Literal descriptions may not tell a universal story. One person's toy collection is another person's unhealthy inability to grow up. If the reader is meant to imagine a wall bursting with treasures, the impression should be glittering and magical. If the reader is meant to be alarmed, it is a grotesque display of decapitated hunting trophies.

**Don't just say what it is. Tell us how to feel about it.**

Comment: Indeed. There is a scene in "Stig of the Dump" where the kids come across large amount of burglar's loot that has been used to decorate a cave person's lair. Think diamond necklaces used like christmas garlands, cutlery stuck in the dirt to stand up and glitter. My children made me read that scene twice they loved it so much. You can do a compelling inventory, but you do it by focusing on being compelling, not an inventory.

Comment: I think you hit the spot. I was focusing too much on the single items rather than on the picture I wanted to give. I like the blurring objects into the next and the opposing factions!

Answer (score 1):

"The shelves were coated, like snow, with items, from books to bottles, statues to jewelry. _______ (I don't know the situation. Put what your MC's thoughts are for first person, or something else to break up the list). I looked at them closer. Touched them, made sure I wasn't dreaming. Nearly everything jumped out at me. A miniature of Michelangelo's David. A bottle of Roman wine. A rough draft of A Tale of Two Cities. He (or I) had everything I could want, need, or even have."

Answer (score 0):

*This list of objects serves no purpose in the rest of the story*

Then you are wasting your time writing, and the reader's time reading, the list and you might want simply to write something like

> The shelves were so higgledy-piggledy with books that John's (or whoever provides the PoV for this scene) inner librarian wanted to reach out and straighten them all up, then set them into alphabetical order.

If you insist on writing a list of items piled on shelves then at least some of them (possibly only one) must be significant for the story. Or maybe you want to use the listing to distract the reader from something else in the scene, such as the identity of the murderer - change as appropriate for your work.